# Why Resource path is coming null in Windows by Java code?

Tags: java, windows

I am writing to get the path of a file

```
if (!new File(path).exists()) {
        URL location = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        if (location == null) {
            location = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path);
        }
        path = location.getPath();
        path = URLDecoder.decode(path, "utf-8");
        path = new File(path).getPath();

        if (!new File(path).exists()) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to resolve path: " + path);
        }
    }
```

the same code working for Linux machine but for Windows i am getting `location = Null`  and  `path=./../config/equipmenttemplates/` is already there.

Comment: does your path starts with a slash ??

Comment: This Path is coming dynamically i am working on web application with Jboss server This Path is defined in properties file `EQUIPMENT_TEMPLATE_FILES_LOC=./../config/equipmenttemplates/`  So i am reading from there then try to get `location`

Comment: Ok. I am asking this because most of the time slashes make a lot of difference. Sometimes they work on linux and not on windows and sometimes vice versa. So if you check manually if the path you are getting really exist then it may save you a lot of time