# What is the meaning of ./../ Path in java?

Tags: java

In properties file someone define `path =./../someName/somename1` ..What is the meaning of this `./../`  ?

Comment: also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280656/where-does-and-come-from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`./` the current folder the working file is in

`../` one directory level higher

so `./../` means one level higher than the folder the current working file is in.

Answer (score 8):

`"./"` Represents current directory.

`"../"` means one level up in the hierarchy defined by the path.

Comment: This will work same for Linux as well as Windows Machine?

Comment: Yes. You can safely use it across all platforms.

Comment: Ok but i am getting issue for Linux its working but not for Windows Why any clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471949/why-resource-path-is-coming-null-in-windows-by-java-code

Answer (score 1):

A path always contains the core component and the complete address list required to locate the file. It is mainly significant environment variable of Java environment. In other words it represents a path that is hierarchical sequence of directory and file name elements separated by a special partition. A Path can represent a root, a root and a sequence of names .A path is considered to be an empty path if it consists solely of one name element that is empty. For more details you can move to [resume writing service Indianapolis](http://www.resumewritingserviceindianapolis.us/) from online.

Answer (score 0):

Current directory plus one level up/back/higher.

Let's say that your current directory is /whatever/my/stuff, then this will put you at /whatever/my/ instead of /whatever/my/stuff/

Answer (score 0):

`../` points to the file's parent directory and `./` to the current directory the file is in.

in your example `home/youAreHere/` turns into `home/someName/` which contains `someName1`